# IE11 Can't reach this page, but the page is valid and accessible

Tags: laravel, internet-explorer, datatables

I have a bit of a bizarre problem happening in IE11. I'm running DataTables with server-side processing so I had to create a custom button for exporting the full data set, since the default buttons only export the visible data set.

Here's the Yajra DataTables for Laravel configuration for one of my buttons:

```
'buttons' => [
  ['extend' => 'csv',
   'text' => '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> CSV',
   'action' => 'function(e,dt,node,config){
      var data=$.extend(
        true,
        dt.context[0].oSavedState,
        {
          columns:dt.context[0].aoColumns.map(function(col){
            return {"data":col.data}
          })
        })
      window.location.href = window.location.href + 
        "?action=csv&" + 
        $.param(data);
    }'
  ],
  ...
```

The button works fine, it basically compiles a list of the columns and filters and sends the user to a Laravel route that handles the `action=csv` request and generates an Excel download that triggers automatically in Chrome and Firefox.

In IE11, however, the browser redirects to the Excel download route but throws up a "Can’t reach this page" error message. I can see in the address bar that the URL is correct, and what's odd is that if I just hit Refresh in the browser, the CSV download is triggered and I am given the option to save.

This happens every time I click the download link. **What might cause IE11 to think the page can't be reached, when it can?**

I tried looking at the request/response headers in network tools and everything seems to be just fine. Any ideas?

Also, I tried rewriting my window.location logic to create a hyperlink element, attach it to the DOM, trigger a click, and it still yields the same thing.

***More Information***

I tried a few other things and was able to eject the download process at any point in the code up until final response to the browser. The browser responds with a 200 status code, when I look at the Network Tab and view the Response Body, I can see my CSV content right there with appropriate Content Disposition, Content Length headers. The Content-Type header is text/plain, but changing it to text/csv didn't solve the problem.

If the IE's Network Tab renders everything correctly, why might IE's browser renderer show a Page Can't Be Displayed error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was finally able to resolve the IE/Edge exporting issue and it comes down to query-string length.

The DataTables grid makes a GET request with a whole bunch of properties related to the query (columns that are visible, which filters were applied, etc.).

Sample Request Params:

```
{
  "action": "csv",
  "time": "1529689896632",
  "start": "0",
  "length": "10",
  "order": [
    ["2","asc"],
    ["1","asc"]
  ],
  "search": {
    "search": "",
    "smart": "true",
    "regex": "false",
    "caseInsensitive": "true"
  },
  "columns": [
    {
      "visible": "true",
      "search": {
        "search": "",
        "smart": "true",
        "regex": "false",
        "caseInsensitive": "false"
      },
      "data": "programs"
    },
    // ...
```

Because there are so many columns, these request params create a very lengthy query-string (in the realm of 3-4000 characters). IE and Edge appear to handle query-strings up to a certain length, as I've noticed some bugs come through where the query-string data was truncated.

I ended up reducing the query-string length by omitting unnecessary and default property values needed for the export. Now IE and Edge both immediately respond with the file download instead of throwing a page not found or other bizarre error.

Comment: Jeff we are having the same issue what can we do to fix this ? :)

Comment: Can't you increase the query-string length in IIS?

Comment: I did that and it doesn't work at least not for the excel...will look again.

Comment: Looks here https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/545 our friend SORRY....Appears they had this issue back in the day too....